# Que el formulario de ingreso guarde el usuario online

Tags: c#

Tengo un Control de Acceso a una Aplicación en `C# (WindowsForm)` donde el Procedimiento almacenado de Login me carga bien los datos.

El problema viene cuando intento de generar un ingreso (en otro Form) y en mi tabla de ingresos en `SQL Server` tengo una Columna `IDUSUARIO`, esto quiere decir que el usuario inició sesión en la Aplicación.

He buscado por muchos lados y no logro encontrar la solución o una idea de estructura para poder tener el ID del Usuario que inició sesión y así tener un registro de los Usuarios que realizan Ingresos y Salida de Productos.

Comment: Hay muchas maneras de hacer eso.Has pensado en ir pasando el id del usuario a los distintos formularios? Imagino que desde tu formulario de login llamas a otro formulario. Crea en ese otro formulario un constructor que reciba el id de usuario y llama a ese constructor desde el formulario de login.

Answer (score 1):

Metiendo manos encontré la solución, era más simple de lo que pensé.
Por si algún usuario se encuentra con el mismo problema indico la solución.

en `Program.cs` creo una variable `public static String idusuario;`
haciendo referencia al Form de Login. de la siguiente forma:

```
DataTable Datos = CAPANEGOCIO.CNUsuario.Login(this.txtUsuario.Text, this.txtContraseña.Text);

Program.idusuario = Datos.Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

Bueno eso sería.

Se agradece la disposición a ayudar.

Un abrazo!

Answer (score -1):

la respuesta anterior es como deberías guardar los valores que afectan a toda la app: usando una propiedad publica en la clase Program. pero como se trata de variables de usuario para toda una aplicación de escritorio yo crearía una estructura o un diccionario para almacenar todas las variables de sesion dentro de un solo objeto, esto te ayudará a aprender a como se utilizan las variables de sesion en un ambiente de programación web.

---

**Diccionarios**

en la clase Program

```
  Public Dictionary Session <string,dynamic > = new Dictionary<string,dynamic>()
```

Desde cualquier lugar de tu app

```
 Program.Session["ID"] =  TuUsuario;
```

uso el tipo dynamic debido a que en el puedes almacenar cualquier tipo de dato, ya sea string, int, etc. aunque debes de ser cuidadoso a la hora de leerlo dado que la conversión es implícita así que puedes enfrentarte a que tus tipos de datos no son compatibles.

si no quieres la conversión implícita puedes irte directamente por object, pero tendrás que castear todas las variables cuando las quieras invocar.

```
 Public Dictionary Session<string,object> = new Dictionary<string,object>()
```

si no te interesa mantener el tipo de dato original bien puedes usar simplemente un diccionario de strings

```
  Public Dictionary Session <string,string> = new Dictionary<string,string>()
```

el problema de este último será la conversión de tipos de datos complejos como horas o bytes.

Ventajas : no necesitas declarar ni instanciar ningún otro objeto, únicamente

```
 Program.Session["<<Nombre de llave>>"] = valor
```

para crear una nueva variable almacenada, si el nombre de llave ya existe este sera actualizado.

---

**por el otro lado están las structs**

los structs son mas fáciles de manejar pues limitan su uso a únicamente los que están definidos en la estructura, de esta manera no tendrás problemas en saber si tus datos son los correctos, son mas fáciles de serializar y muy eficientes con LINQ para poblarlas

```
 public static struct Session
 {
        public int IDUsuario;
        public string NombreUsuario; 
 }

 Program.Session.IDUsuario=5;
 Program.Session.NombreUsuario="Yo";
```

Comment: Mas alla de que la pregunta es totalmente basada en opiniones, tu respuesta es bastante rara. No lo digo por la calidad de la misma, si no por lo que estas proponiendo. Usar dynamic u object en un desarrollo de escritorio, es como demasiado. En escritorio sabes lo que tienes, lo que hay, y el lenguaje te ayuda tambien a saber que hay. Hacer un diccionario con clave valor, es totalmente innecesario. Una clase estatica soluciona todos los problemas. Tratar de llevar la web a escritorio es un grave error. En el escritorio las cosas funcionan de otra manera y mas simple.

Comment: variables de sesion no es un tema que se toca mucho en aplicaciones de escritorio, y si, los diccionarios pueden ser un overkill pero simplifican enormemente el tener que crear e instanciar una estructura o clase. 

lo que quería demostrar con la respuesta es que es mejor encapsular los datos en lugar de dejarlos al aire, y de ahí tuve que desarrollar todo el tema de los diccionarios

Comment: "Variables de sesion", que no existen en una app de escritorio, son las mismas variables que estan en la app. Toda app las tiene, por todos lados. Decir que no existen es desconocer como deberia funcionar una app de escritorio. Por ejemplo, cuando abris un archivo, y despues tenes que guardarlo, tu app sabe donde lo abrio y donde lo debe guardar. No son variables de sesion, son las variables del sistema, y en los de escritorio estan por todos lados. Mas que un overkill, esto es totalmente innecesario. Cualquier clase estatica soluciona el problema.

Comment: El problema es tratar de replicar un entorno que existio despues, a uno anterior. No, no debe hacerse eso. Las reglas de las apps de escritorio no tienen que bajarse al nivel de los problemas que tienen las apps webs.

Comment: Desarrollar apps de escritorio != Desarrollar web apps != Desarrollar Apps móviles != Desarrollar cloud apps. //Se puede compartir conceptos pero la forma, el paradigma es diferente

Comment: Y no se como hacer una estructura de diccionario mejora a hacer una clase autocontenida, que sabes que tiene y que no, y que se instancia en una linea. No entiendo esa parte de tener que crear una clase e instanciarla.. es algo trivial en una app de escritorio. si quieres, lo podemos charlar un poco mas en el [chat]. pero no, por su contenido, es una mala respuesta.

Comment: error, las variables de sistema pueden reconocer tus credenciales y quien eres al utilizar una aplicación, las variables de sesión son definidas por el usuario y no dependen del ambiente si no de la aplicación. 
No puedes utilizar una variable de sistema de datos extraídos de una base de datos. por eso defines tus propias propiedades. 
el usuario necesita almacenar variables de globales, por no llamarlas de sesión